# Combo line and bar chart. how can i render line in middle

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, chart.js

Current Behavior
When i extend my Scale like this

```
  determineDataLimits: function () {
    var min = Math.min.apply(null, this.chart.data.datasets[0].data)
    console.log(this)
    console.log(defaultConfigObject)
    Chart.options.scales.rightSide.ticks.min = function () {
      minValue + 5
      return minValue
    }
    this.options.ticks.min = minValue
  }
})

Chart.scaleService.registerScaleType('myScale', MyScale, defaultConfigObject)
```

and use this type in options on ticks
i gives me a console error that tells me that cannot read property of data undefined.

and when i console log defaultConfigObject it returns undefined.

what should i use instead of defaultConfigObject?

Expected Behavior

I want it to render my chart so i can modify where my line should start. i want it to render my line on the middle on the Y-axis on my combo line and bar diagram. with dynamic data

Environment

Chart.js version: vue

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misread the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html). It states (emphasis mine):

> Once you have created your scale class, you need to register it with the global chart object so that it can be used. ***A default config for the scale may be provided when registering the constructor***. The first parameter to the register function is a string key that is used later to identify which scale type to use for a chart.
>
> ```
> Chart.scaleService.registerScaleType('myScale', MyScale, defaultConfigObject);
> ```

This is saying that ***you*** may provide an object to be passed in to your scale class when it is registered. `defaultConfigObject` is simply placeholder text to show the `registerScaleType` function signature. So for example you might do this:

```
 Chart.scaleService.registerScaleType('myScale', MyScale, { myprop: true });
```